# Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call. Insert 'from <Decoder>

Tags: swift, codable

**I have a struct which confirm codable protocol.**

```
public struct FlightDTO {
   public var flightName: String = ""
   public var PilotName: String = ""
   public var copilotName: String = ""
   public var totalCrewMem: Int = 0
}

extension FlightDTO: Codable {
 
 enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
 case flightName
 case PilotName
 case copilotName
 case totalCrewMem
 }
 }
```

when I create object of struct it give me this initialiser.

> This struct is in swift package and I am initialising it from the app.

```
  var flightData = FlightDTO(from: <#Decoder#>)
```

> I am not sure what to pass in decoder.

Comment: It give me error please pass missing argument from decoder . I found this answer but it didn't help me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66916479/missing-argument-for-parameter-from-in-call-insert-from-decoder

Comment: The default initializer (`FlightDTO()`) is still available as well as the memberwise initializer by pressing ⌥ ↩ after typing `FlightDTO(` and selecting the initializer from the code completion suggestion. And if you are the author of the package consolidate the spelling and make `pilotName` lowercase. And remove the default values from the struct members. The code compiles anyway.

Comment: thanks for your comment below answer by joakim helped.

Comment: @vadian the synthesised init is internal so you need to create your own to make it public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The init that is suggested is used by the JSONDecoder when decoding JSON but to create objects manually in code you need to create your own public init because the synthesised one is internal.

So either

```
public init() {}  // use default values
```

or

```
public init FlightDTO(flightName: String, PilotName: String, copilotName: String, totalCrewMem: Int) {
    self.flightName = flightName
    self.PilotName = PilotName
    self.copilotName = copilotName
    self.totalCrewMem = totalCrewMem
}
```

Comment: it worked for me, you saved my day. Since yesterday I was struggling with this issue. Thanks a lot